# MySQL request COUNT issue

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I want to calculate the number of patients seen in each clinic during the last month, so this is the request what I used :

```
SELECT dispensaire.IdDisp, 
 COUNT(SELECT consultation.NumDossier 
       FROM consultation 
       WHERE consultation.Date IN (SELECT consultation.Date 
                                   FROM consultation 
                                   WHERE consultation.Date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE( ))) 
FROM dispensaire, medecin, consultation 
WHERE dispensaire.IdDisp=medecin.IdDisp 
  AND medecin.IdDisp.consultation.IdDisp 
GROUP BY dispensaire.IdDisp
```

I can't find what's wrong in my request ! thanks

Comment: I went to format this query and the formatter exploded.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO that's because there's an `AND` floating around

Comment: Are you getting an error or just the results are not what's expected?  The second AND in the where clause seems to be missing an = . perhaps you mean `AND medecin.idDisp = consultation.IdDisp`

Comment: nested queries in the select clause and old syntax...there is no way a formatter would figure that out.  @Ziko - this query needs quite a bit to get it to work.  MYSQL performs horribly with that syntax.  Your select line should read  dispensaire.IdDisp, count(*)...the rest of the subquery logic should be in there where statement. (bluefeet beat me to an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the following line - it is missing the equal sign between the two columns:

```
AND medecin.IdDisp.consultation.IdDisp
```

The line should be:

```
AND medecin.IdDisp = consultation.IdDisp
```

I might suggest rewriting your query to something like this, which uses JOIN syntax on your tables instead of the join in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT d.IdDisp, 
 COUNT(c.NumDossier)
FROM dispensaire d
INNER JOIN medecin m
    ON d.IdDisp = m.IdDisp 
INNER JOIN consultation c
    ON m.IdDisp = c.IdDisp
WHERE c.Date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE( ))
GROUP BY d.IdDisp
```